# Mostrar categorias y subcategorias

Tags: laravel, blade

Buenas ya llevo rato intentando y no doy con respuesta, lo que quiero hacer es simplemente mostrar en mi home categorías y subcategorías. El componente ya lo tengo listo solamente me falta que se vean las categorías principales.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi bucle dentro de la vista "app.blade.php".

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <div class="relative" @mouseenter="open = '{{ $loop->index }}'" @mouseleave="open = null">
        <a href="{{ route('by-category', $category) }}" class="text-white text-lg transition ease-out hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-black rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">
            {{ $category->title }} <i :class="open === '{{ $loop->index }}' ? 'fa-chevron-down': 'fa-chevron-up'" class="fas ml-2"></i>
        </a>
        <div x-show="open === '{{ $loop->index }}'" 
            @mouseenter="open = '{{ $loop->index }}'" 
            @mouseleave="open = null" 
            class="z-40 bg-black inline-flex flex-col justify-center items-center absolute top-full left-0 right-0 p-3"
        >
            @foreach($category->subCategory as $subCategory)  
                <a href="{{ route('by-category', $subCategory) }}" class="text-white text-center text-lg transition ease-out hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-black rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">
                    {{ $subCategory->title }}
                </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

PostController le tira estas variables al home, home esta utilizando la layout de app.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::query()
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->where('published_at', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
            ->with('categories')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();

        $latestPost = $posts->shift();

        $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')
            ->with('subCategory')
            ->get();

        // dd($categories);
     
        return view('home', compact('posts', 'latestPost', 'categories'));
    }
```

El dd me tira bien la colección puedo ver las categorías principales y las que tengo como subcategorías.

Esto tengo en mi modelo de Category:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 
        'slug', 
        'parent_id'
    ];

    public function posts(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'category_post', 'category_id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

Luego mi tabla de category, esta es la manera en como asigno una subcategoría a una categoría, mediante la columna de `parent_id`.

```
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 2048);
            $table->string('slug', 2048);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

No tengo ningun problema con guardarlas sólo al pasarlas al front end, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución la encontré en un componente que ya tenía creado, este componente lo estaba utilizando para tirar las variables en cuanto a las categorías, osea que ya había un componente encargado de tirar las categorías. Lo que quería hacer era que desde la relación de los posts me diera las categorías. En el PostController tenía unos eager loading con las categorías pero la relación que tienen los posts y las categorías nunca incluían a las subcategorías.

```
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        $categories = Category::query()
            ->join('category_post', 'categories.id', '=', 'category_post.category_id')
            ->select('categories.title', 'categories.slug', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('categories.id')
            ->orderByDesc('total')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();

        $allCategories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')
            ->with('subCategory')
            ->get();
            
        return view('layouts.app', compact('categories', 'allCategories'));
    }
```

Agrege mi variable de `allCategorías` y listo.